How do I call the equiv. of `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` using `pyo3`?
Consider this example derived from the pyo3 tests:
#[pyclass]
struct ClassWithGetAttribute;

#[pymethods]
impl ClassWithGetAttribute {
    fn __getattribute__(&self, name: &str) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
        if name == "exists" {
            Ok(42)
        } else {
            // return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
            PyAny::call_method(&self, "__getattribute__", (name,), None) // <- this doesn't work.
        }
    }
}


Next time, tag your question with a language too ([rust]), so users have better chance of finding it.

You can just evaluate the expression object.__getattribute__ and call it. This won't be as fast as your solution, but if performance isn't a concern this is better and without unsafe:
#[pyclass(dict)]
struct ClassWithGetAttribute;

#[pymethods]
impl ClassWithGetAttribute {
    #[new]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn __getattribute__<'py>(
        this: &Bound<'py, Self>,
        py: Python<'py>,
        name: &str,
    ) -> PyResult<Bound<'py, PyAny>> {
        if name == "exists" {
            Ok(42i32.into_py(py).into_bound(py))
        } else {
            let object = py.eval_bound("object.__getattribute__", None, None)?;
            object.call1((this, name))
        }
    }
}

Of course, it is better to cache the value:
#[pyclass(dict)]
struct ClassWithGetAttribute;

#[pymethods]
impl ClassWithGetAttribute {
    #[new]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }

    fn __getattribute__<'py>(
        this: &Bound<'py, Self>,
        py: Python<'py>,
        name: &str,
    ) -> PyResult<PyObject> {
        if name == "exists" {
            Ok(42i32.into_py(py))
        } else {
            static OBJECT_GETATTRIBUTE: GILOnceCell<PyObject> = GILOnceCell::new();
            let object_getattribute = OBJECT_GETATTRIBUTE.get_or_try_init(py, || {
                py.eval_bound("object.__getattribute__", None, None)
                    .map(|f| f.unbind())
            })?;
            object_getattribute.call1(py, (this, name))
        }
    }
}


Isn't this going to do self.__getattribute__(name) instead of object.__getattribute__(self, name)?

Performance is a concern as this sits in a hot path.. however the caching may resolve that issue.

@Kaos It will not be as efficient even with caching.

I managed to get this working by reverse engineering the pyo3 implementation of __getattribute__, but I wonder if this is the proper way to handle this?
    fn __getattribute__(
        self_: &PyCell<Self>,
        name: String,
        py: Python,
    ) -> PyResult<*mut ffi::PyObject> {
        // ...
        unsafe {
            let slf = self_.borrow_mut().into_ptr();
            let attr = name.into_py(py).into_ptr();
            let res = ffi::PyObject_GenericGetAttr(slf, attr);
            if res.is_null() {
                Err(PyErr::fetch(py))
            } else {
                Ok(res)
            }
        }


Definitely not.
